# Trouble installing JAR package for Databricks Labs Smolder Project

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jar, databricks, azure-databricks

I attempted to follow the readme here: https://github.com/databrickslabs/smolder

When I run the imports in Azure Databricks with runtime 8.4 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)

```
import com.databricks.labs.smolder.functions.parse_hl7_message

command-2210167876712732:1: error: object labs is not a member of package com.databricks
import com.databricks.labs.smolder.functions.parse_hl7_message
```

I followed the steps to "To create a JAR that can be run as part of an Apache Spark job or shell, run: package" with but it failed too and I get sevral error messages including 'head' unknown.

```
cd Downloads/smolder-master
sbt package

[info] Loading settings for project smolder-master-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /Downloads/smolder-master/project
[info] Loading settings for project core from version.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to smolder (in build file:/Downloads/smolder-master/)
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 128
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:30)
```

Not sure what if I did part of building the package incorrectly but at a loss for how to fix the import issue.

Comment: did you built smolder correctly? you need to run `sbt package` in the `smolder-master` directory. If it fails, add error message to your post. Also, what Databricks Runtime are you using?

Comment: @AlexOtt Updated post to include runtime and error when running in smolder-master directory

Comment: have you cloned this repository, or downloaded it? It looks like you need to clone it, because build script relies on `git` command to obtain the Git commit hash